# ArrayList not available outside of listener

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a JTable. When the user selects a columns the idea is that the float data is added to an ArrayList. I'll try to do some stats on the arrayList later on.

At the moment I am managing to add the required data to the ArrayList and can see the data when I print to the console from within the listener. However the data isnt available from outside of the listener even theough the ArrayList is declared from outside of the Listener.

```
        TableColumnModel columnModelCompareL = table_CompareL.getColumnModel();
         ArrayList<Float> statsCompareL=new ArrayList<Float>();
         columnModelCompareL.addColumnModelListener(new TableColumnModelListener() {
                    public void columnSelectionChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                          Object[] data = columnToArray(table_CompareL,table_CompareL.getSelectedColumn());
                        System.out.println("MY data length"+data.length);
                        try {
                            for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                                if (data[i]!=null){
                                try {
                                    statsCompareL.add(Float.parseFloat((data[i]).toString().trim()));
                                } catch (Exception e1) {
                                    System.out.println("nought to add here");
                                }
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
                            System.out.println("You haven't selected a numeric column. Please select again");
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void columnAdded(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void columnRemoved(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void columnMoved(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void columnMarginChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    }
                });

        System.out.println("statsCompareL"+statsCompareL);
```

Comment: Have you tried to declare the ArrayList outside of any method in the class?By doing so it will be available anywere inside your class.

Comment: Yes. I've put it right at the top of the class.  I wondered if it was because I was returning void from the listener but it doesnt seem to list ArrayList<Float> instead of void

Comment: If you expect your last code line to print anything: it will not. Because that code line is executed during the creation the of ui, but the listener is called much later (while the user interacts with the ui).

Comment: So how do I pass the ArrayList from one Listener to another?

Comment: Have you tried adding a button with an action listener that writes out the ArrayList?

Comment: Aha you were right.I was looking at the System.out.println of the ArrayList outside of the second Listener assuming that would give me the ArraList but I guess this gets called when the frame is empty so its inevitably empty. Want to post as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updated ArrayList is not visible inside your UI construction code (since this code finishes long before the ArrayList is updated).

It is however available within other event listeners:

```
     TableColumnModel columnModelCompareL = table_CompareL.getColumnModel();
     ArrayList<Float> statsCompareL=new ArrayList<Float>();
     columnModelCompareL.addColumnModelListener(new TableColumnModelListener() {
         // implementation left out for brevity
     });

     // this runs during construction time, long before statsCompareL is updated
     System.out.println("statsCompareL"+statsCompareL);

     JButton testButton = new JButton("Test ArrayList");
     testButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             // this runs after the button is clicked, so it will see the changes statsCompareL
             System.out.println("statsCompareL"+statsCompareL);
         }
     });
     // add the button somewhere convenient for testing purposes
```